# Facebook API returns uncomplete data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am reading user information from Facebook as follows:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $appId,
        'secret' => $secret,
        'cookie' => true
    ));
    $fb_user = $facebook->getUser();
    $user_data = $facebook->api('/me');
```

This works for vast majority of users, but for minority of them facebook does not return all data i need. For them it returns 
**$user_data['first_name']** and **$user_data['last_name']** as usual, but **$user_data['email']** is empty.

Problem is not that said users do not have email set in facebook at first place because I know that user on whom I noticed the problem has it set.

And it should not be insufficient permissions because in javascript when logging user in I ask for **scope:'email'** explicitly (and I also have verified that it really does asks user for email permission)

```
FB.login(
    function(response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
            login(); // call to php file in question
        } 
    }, 
    {scope:'email'}
);
```

I don't know what to do. What puzzles me most is that it works flawlessly for other users because it suggests that generally everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Some users may have opted out to give your application access to their email. Your app should handle the case when someone has declined to grant your app one of the permissions you requested.

> Revoked Permissions
>
> People can also revoke permissions granted to your app in Facebook's >interface at any time after they have logged in. It is important that your >app regularly checks which permissions have been granted, especially when >launching on a new platform. We provide methods for you to check what >permissions are currently granted to your app.

Comment: Thanks for feeadback, but I know this is NOT the case. I have access to one of problematic account and i have tested this.

Comment: Not all users will have a reachable email address on file, have you confirmed that they do?

Comment: @Igy Does it have to be reachable for Facebook to return it? 
One of our customer support agents can not log into our website, because facebook api does not return her email address. But we know that she has email listed on facebook, and that she did not revoke permission.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be reachable for the API to return it - your login flow should never assume an email address will always be available, because some users won't have an address (and some will have one that's bouncing and thus not returned, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Use $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,picture,name,email');

Comment: I will test it, but I doubt. Email is marked as default in documentation, and it is returned for majority of users.

Comment: nah it wasnt returning in my case too,  had to add it manually and now all is working fine. tell me after u test it.

Comment: Where in the documentation is it listed as 'default'? since v2.4 all fields need to be enumerated, only name and id may be returned by default

Comment: @SalmanAslam I tested it and it did not change the outcome. Profiles from which i received email before I still do, I those that I did no I still don't.

Comment: Then this is simple. when your app ask for permissions and someone declines then your app able to access user's public items only, it will not get email id if it is not public.

Comment: try Use $facebook->api('/me?fields=email'); and check what error message it gives to you in response

Comment: @SalmanAslam I tried and it does not return error message. just id. (id and email for other users).

Comment: Then this is for sure the problem of permissions. try some user random id to use your app and then check for permission.
You can also popup for permissions again if user has declined it.

Comment: @SalmanAslam I really appreciate your efforts, but it is not the case. as I said in response to Marcus Nyberg's answear, I have access to one of the problematic accounts and i have verified personally that user is giving us email permission.

Comment: @LukášRutar if uou have access to one of these accounts. Please  go into user profile's about section and in contact and basic info section see what is privacy level for email.

Comment: @SalmanAslam its is private, but user is granting our website email permission. should not that overrule that?

Comment: @LukášRutar You will never know as facebook keeps changing its settings. i am also tired of them. i gave you a direcion. Try changing it to  public and then friends and test it for both cases. it will give you answer that this is the problem or not.